# Does gdb not step into pointer accesses?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to debug using gdb. Say a function is accessed through pointers

```
test->Function_to_be_called();
```

When I step using gdb, I expected it to step into Function_to_be_called(), however, that does not seem to happen and the symbols are not resolved. Is there any workaround in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

gdb's `s` (`step`) command will only step into functions when debug symbols (line number info) is available for the function.  If the function is in an object with no debug info, it will be stepped over (like the `n` command).

You can still step into the function using the `si` (`stepi`) command which steps by single machine instructions.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931242/unable-to-step-into-a-function-in-a-shared-library-with-gdb/59331366#59331366)